# How to add capabilities to rkt container

Tags: docker, coreos, rkt

I'm very new to [rkt](https://coreos.com/rkt/) (coming from docker).  In docker I can add `NET_ADMIN` capabilities to a container:

```
docker run -d -p 53:53/tcp --cap-add=NET_ADMIN my_image
```

How do I do this in `rkt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to add capabilities to the default set at runtime in rkt. However, [as of v1.9.0](https://github.com/coreos/rkt/blob/v1.9.0/Documentation/subcommands/run.md#options), you can specify capabilities to remove from that set or you can override them with your own set.

To achieve an equivalent set of capabilities, you can take [docker's default capability set](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/v1.11.2/oci/defaults_linux.go#L64-L79) and add `CAP_NET_ADMIN`:

```
rkt run my_image --cap-retain="CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FSETID,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_MKNOD,CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SYS_CHROOT,CAP_KILL,CAP_AUDIT_WRITE,CAP_NET_ADMIN"
```